# Laravel user capabilities

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Within Laravel you can easily [define abilities](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#defining-abilities) and then hook into them later on a user request regarding to do different actions:

```
$gate->define('update-post', function ($user, $post) {
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
});
```

But almost all my defined abilities has this part `$user->id === $model->user_id` in it. I don't like it as it's a kind of repeating a condition over and over which I think could be more abstract.

Most of my defined abilities are according to updating/deleting records, so it would be better if I could make a global condition applied to all of them or if there could be a group ability defining which is like to what we do in routing.

Is there any workaround for it? I really like it DRY.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything in Laravel is extendable, that's the power of its service providers.

You can extend the `Gate` object to a `MyCustomGate` object and do whatever you want in that object. Here's an example:

**MyCustomGate.php**

```
class MyCustomGate extends \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate
{
    protected $hasOwnershipVerification = [];

    /**
     * Define a new ability.
     *
     * @param  string  $ability
     * @param  callable|string  $callback
     * @return $this
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function defineWithOwnership($ability, $callback, $foreignUserIdKey = "user_id")
    {
        // We will add this 
        $this->hasOwnershipVerification[$ability] = $foreignUserIdKey;

        return $this->define($ability, $callback);
    }

    /**
     * Resolve and call the appropriate authorization callback.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
     * @param  string  $ability
     * @param  array  $arguments
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function callAuthCallback($user, $ability, array $arguments)
    {
        $callback = $this->resolveAuthCallback(
            $user, $ability, $arguments
        );

        // We will assume that the model is ALWAYS the first key
        $model = is_array($arguments) ? $arguments[0] : $arguments;

        return $this->checkDirectOwnership($ability, $user, $model) && call_user_func_array(
            $callback, array_merge([$user], $arguments)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Check if the user owns a model.
     *
     * @param  string  $ability
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function checkDirectOwnership($ability, $user, $model)
    {
        if(!isset($this->hasOwnershipVerification[$ability])) {
            return true
        }

        $userIdKey = $this->hasOwnershipVerification[$ability];

        // getAuthIdentifier() is just ->id, but it's better in case the pk of a user is different that id
        return $user->getAuthIdentifier() == $model->{$userIdKey};
    }
}
```

Then, you will have to tell Laravel to use your gate instead of the default one. You ca do that in your `AuthServiceProvider` (assuming that it's extending `Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider`, just add the following method.

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
/**
 * Register the access gate service.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function registerAccessGate()
{
    $this->app->singleton(\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate::class, function ($app) {
        return new MyCustomGate($app, function () use ($app) {
            return $app['auth']->user();
        });
    });
}
```

And this way, you can define abilities using `defineWithOwnership()` method instead of `define()`. You can still use `define()` for abilities that don't require ownership verification. There's a third parameter `defineWithOwnership()` accepts which is `$foreignUserIdKey`; that's used for the case when a model has a different field for the user id.

Note: I wrote the code on the fly and did not try it, it may have errors, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you Blue. That's a nice and clean approach but what I can get out of it is just an error for now `Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #1 [ <required> callable $userResolver ]] in class Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate`

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that custom overridden `registerAccessGate()` method is not getting called.

Comment: Alright, is your `AuthServiceProvider` extending Laravel's `AuthServiceProvider`? Are you using a custom `register()` method? Another way to register it would be to rename the function to something else and then call that function after `parent::register()` in your `register()` method.

Comment: A full exception stack would be useful (omitting any sensitive information). You can use a paste bin and link it here.

Comment: My `AuthServiceProvider` class extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` by its default. I'm not using a custom `register()` method inside my `AuthServiceProvider` but as you offered I wrote one `public register();` and called both `parent::register()` and the renamed form of `registerAccessGate()` method. Yet I'm receiving the exact same error I commented above. I pasted related laravel.log part [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/GpvL2cgL).

Comment: Alright, here's another thing. I guess you're injecting a `Gate` instance somewhere in your `AuthServiceProvider`. Are you importing `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate` or `Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate`? Because in the later case, Laravel will try to guess the dependencies of `Gate` class, but if you inject a `Gate` interface, Laravel will resolve it from the `Container`. Make sure you are importing `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate`.

Comment: Okay, I changed `boot()`'s argument `$gate`'s type from `GateContract` which extends `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate` to `MyCustomGate` which lives under `App\Providers` namespace [`App\Providers\MyCustomGate`] only. The other things are left intact as your answer provided.

Comment: Your `boot()` should in fact extend the `GateContract`. That's why we're binding `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate`. So, what you will do is: create a new service provider (ex: `GateServiceProvider` extending  `Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider`, make sure it's exactly this class and not: `Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider`. put the  `registerAccessGate()` in it and leave it empty. Then, you should put `GateServiceProvider` right after `Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider` in your `app/config.php` file.

Comment: Reading your logs further, there's a service provider with its name starting with M. It's unclear from the logs, they only show: `Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Providers\\M...', Array)`. So check if there's any service provider starting with M that has a method requiring `Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate`. They should always require: `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract`.

Comment: Regarding to your last comment, that's the `MyCustomGate.php` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103818/discussion-between-blue-genie-and-revo).

Comment: I ended up using global `$container` variable in replacement to `$hasOwnershipVerification`.

Answer (score 5):

I checked your question quite a bit, but I've found no "easy" way to do it.

Instead, what I would probably do is this:

```
<?php


namespace App\Policies;

 use App\User;
 use App\Post;

trait CheckOwnership {
    protected function checkOwnership($user, $model) {
        $owned = $user->id === $model->user_id;
        if ($owned === false)
             throw new NotOwnedException;
    }    
 }

 class PostPolicy
 {

     use CheckOwnership;

    public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
         try {
             $this->checkOwnership($user, $post);
             //continue other checks
         } catch (NotOwnedException $ex) {
             return false;
         } 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this function to your AuthServiceProvider

```
    public function defineAbilities(array $abilities, $gate)
    {
        foreach($abilities as $name => $model){
            $gate->define($name, function ($user, $model){
                return $user->id === ${$model}->user_id;
            });
        }
    }
```

and then inside boot method

```
$this->defineAbilities(['ability1' => 'model1', 'ability2' => 'model2'], $gate);
```

Comment: Thanks but I didn't say my abilities return one and only `$user->id === $model->user_id` result. I said it **has** this part in it so it could be like `$user->id == $post->user_id && $post->status == 0`.

Answer (score 4):

You can define another function and call it within the anonymous function. This will allow you to have commonly-used code in one central location while still allowing any resource-specific logic.

Add this function to your `AuthServiceProvider` class:

```
public function userCheck(User $user, $target)
{
    // do the user id check
    $result = isset($target->user_id) && isset($user) && $user->id === $target->user_id;
    return $result;
}
```

Your code, modified:

```
$gate->define('update-post', function ($user, $post) {
    // call the function
    $result = $this->userCheck($user, $post);
    // do some kind of 'update-post' specific check
    return $result/* && some_bool_statement*/;
});
```

Comment: Sliphon I came to something weird: `define`'s second argument should be of type `callable` only. Any workarounds?

Comment: Siphon it seems `$user` and `$post` as `userCheck()`'s first and second arguments are not passed to the function: `Undefined variable: user`

Comment: If you can modify your answer for a working solution, then I won't hesitate to award another bounty.

Comment: I've updated my answer to something more elegant. It seems Closures would make the code unnecessarily complicated. What you need to do can be easily done with a simple helper function to consolidate logic.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use middlewares.

Simply make a admin middleware and use it in your routes and routes group.

And there is no security bug on your project (delete, create & ... actions) because Laravel has csrf token!

You can use [`before()`](http://file:///D:/Tutorials%20&%20docs/Laravel%205.1%20docs/Authorization%20-%20Laravel%20-%20The%20PHP%20Framework%20For%20Web%20Artisans.htm#writing-policies) function, also.

And then an important note:

if you don't define a correspond function on Policy class and call it `$this->authorize($post)` on a controller an `unauthorized Action` error will be thrown unless `before()`method`return`s`true`.

for example call `$this->authorize` on `Dashboard\PostsController`:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id)->first();
    $this->authorize($post);
    return view('dashboard.post')->with(compact('post'));
}
```

and if we defined a PostPolicy Class:

```
class PostPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function before($user, $ability)
    {
        return $user->is_admin;
    }
}
```

If user be admin he/she can edit post because we `return`ed `true` in `before()` method despite of have not a method with same name (as `edit` method in `PostsController`).

In fact Laravel will check for before method mthod on `Policy Class`. if `before return`'s`null` will check for correspond method with same name on controller method and if this method not found user cannot perform action.

Thank you laravel for DRY us!♥